# How do I populate Select menu options from SQL database using Bootstrap framework and PHP?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli

I am creating a simple form that has a Select menu that will need to be populated using a SQL query that identifies all the unique values from single table and single column.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  </head>
  <body>
```

This is an example of the Select menu that I want...

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="db_test_bs.php">
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="inputLocation" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Location</label>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
       <select class="form-control" id="inputLocation" name="inputLocation">
          <option>Smith</option>
          <option>Henry</option>
          <option>Jackson</option>
          <option>Hamilton</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is the Select menu that I am trying to populate using a query...

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputLocation" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Location</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <select class="form-control" id="inputLocation" name="inputLocation">
        </select>

    <?php
      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "owner_1";
      $password = "owner_1";
      $dbname = "test1";

    // Create Connection
      $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
      if (!$conn) {
          trigger_error("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
          }
    //Run Query
      $stmt = "SELECT DISTINCT `CUST_NAME` FROM `customer` WHERE 1";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$stmt) or die(mysqli_error());
        while(list($category) = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
          $option = '<option value="'.$category.'">'.$category.'</option>';
          echo ($option);
        }

      mysqli_close($conn);
   ?>

     </div>
  </div>
</form>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result from the code above is two Select menus.  One that is static options that are hard coded and the other Select menu does not contain any options.

Using WAMP and BootStrap 3.
I am new to web dev so any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: why are you echoing your `echo ($option);` after you close your select `</select>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be :

```
<select class="form-control" id="inputLocation" name="inputLocation">
...
//Your PHP Code
...
</select>
```

Note : You not really need `WHERE 1` in your query for this case. You can echo directly the result without asiggn it into variable Like this :

`echo '<option value="'.$category.'">'.$category.'</option>';`

Comment: Thank you for the input.  I made these changes, but the menu is still blank.

Comment: What menu? do you mean `echo $category` didn't give any result? Have you checked your query in mysql panel or `echo $category`  without `<option>` ?

Comment: Correct, `echo $category` did not give a result.  To test the PHP and SQL query, saved the PHP as a seperate file and added the following code to the html file. `<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="select_option.php">`  `<input type = "submit" value = "ExecuteQuery"/>`  `</form>`

Comment: My comment above timed out...  The added input executes the php file without error, returning the proper query results, but on the [link] (http://localhost/...select_option.php) page rather than options of the Select.  I believe that this adequately tests the php and the query.  What else can I do to troubleshoot?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code except I listed above. http://i.imgur.com/bk3AEUZ.png Did you get any error? Are you sure your **exact** query give you results in mysql panel?

Comment: I do not get any errors.  Yes, it is the exact query.  The Select menu is being populated with one option  '.$category.'.

Comment: try with another table which have result, or invalid table to give you any errors. Because there is nothing wrong with your code as you can see in my previous screencshoot.

Comment: It does not appear that my PHP code runs if it is "embedded" in the html code.

Comment: I was saving the code as html rather than php.  Changed extension to PHP and now the Select options are accurately populated from the database.

Answer (score 0):

(as mentioned by @Sean) You you have closed off your `<select></select>` tag before the PHP, so your PHP loop is running out side of the `<select>` element

Also as a best practice you should fix your `mysqli_error()` statement by passing the `$conn` variable into the `mysqli_error` function like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$stmt) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

**Note:** You should have PHP error reporting on in a dev environment.

Here is updated code

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputLocation" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Location</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <select class="form-control" id="inputLocation" name="inputLocation">

            <?php
               $servername = "localhost";
               $username = "owner_1";
               $password = "owner_1";
               $dbname = "test1";

            // Create Connection
            $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

            // Check connection
            if (!$conn) {
                trigger_error("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

            }
            //Run Query
            $stmt = "SELECT DISTINCT `CUST_NAME` FROM `customer` WHERE 1";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$stmt) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            while(list($category) = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
                echo '<option value="'.$category.'">'.$category.'</option>';
            }


            mysqli_close($conn);
            ?>

            </select>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your username, password and database has been changed.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I have updated now. I created a temporary table and user to test my code  against. So I can confirm this code works. If the OP's code still isnt working for them, then I would suspect the problem lies somewhere else.